# can't manage to print different values from different rows from file

Tags: bash, awk

i am trying to print values from two rows in one row. I am using awk with arrays, but can't do that. I have a file:

```
 1 00 ERROR
124 00 INFO
  1 01 ERROR
 60 01 INFO
  1 02 ERROR
 44 02 INFO
...
```

and would like to get something like that:

```
00 1 124
01 1 60
02 1 44
...
```

Comment: Where are the values coming from? For example your first line of output is `00 1 124`. Obviously the `124` came from the 2nd line of your input but did the `00` come from line 1 or line 2 and did the `1` come from line 1 or line 3? Don't just say "I want this", tell us which input rows/columns are being mapped to which output rows/columns so we're not guessing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Pure *POSIX* shell, (i.e. `bash`, `dash`, etc.):

   ```
   while read a b c && read d e f ; do echo $b $a $d ; done < afile
   ```
2. *GNU* [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/):

   ```
   datamash -W -g2 unique 1 < afile | tr ',\t' '  '
   ```

Either of which outputs:

```
00 1 124
01 1 60
02 1 44
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
awk '{s=$2" "$1; getline; print s,$1}' in.txt
```

1. store $1 and $1 to variable s.
2. `getline` will read next line.
3. print result